# Where do I find the Github source code for the Forge Responsive Connected Database's Demos?

Tags: autodesk-forge

The Github source links for Forge Responsive Connected Database's [Demo](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator) seem to be broken. Well, I already found the the right sources but maybe it can help someone else. For example, the following source link changed
**from** https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.PointCloudMarkup
**to** https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.PointCloudMarkup
in the current state of the master branch. So the path changed in the middle
**from** `../viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/..`
**to** `../components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/..`

Btw, would this be the right place to report broken/missing documentation, demos etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Concern.

BTW is the older broken link mentioned anywhere on demo website?

You can email forge.help@autodesk.com for any queries related to forge.

If the query is technical and generic, we encourage to ask on stackoverflow so that it can be helpful for others as well.

Comment: Yes, the link is accessible via the GitHub-Icon right besides "Source on"

Comment: Got it. Thanks Dominik. I will do a pull request to fix the links.